# .htaccess - Deny from all , allow from ip list

Tags: .htaccess

i want to deny all ips to my server and allow just those from whitelist.txt

example:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from  whitelist.txt
```

so whitelist can be in whatever format just is there a way to list there all ip address, example one per line ,

Comment: I don't believe that is possible with Apache.

Comment: You can use `RewriteMap`